# Stripe cancellation of subscription is not working with Django

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a cancellation page to remove a subscription of monthly payment. 
However, I still cannot retrieve the customer information with Stripe API.

The customer and subscription is already succeeded to create when I saw the Dashboard of Stripe.

Here is my views.py:

```
def charge(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = CustomUserForm(request.POST)
          try:
              user = form.save()
              plan = 'plan_xxxxxx'
              customer = stripe.Customer.create( 
                  card=customer.stripe_id,
                  email=user.email, 
                  plan=plan)

              charge = stripe.Subscription.create(
                  customer=customer.id,
                  plan=plan,
                  )
              user.stripe_id = customer.id
              user.save()

          return render(request, 'charge.html')
```

Here is cancel the subscription in views.py:

```
def cancel_subscription(request):
    try:
        customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve(request.user.stripe_id)  
        customer.cancel_subscription(at_period_end=True)
        return redirect('home')

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    return render(request, 'accounts/cancel.html')
```

Here is cancel the subscription in model.py:

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
   username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   email = models.EmailField()
   stripe_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   plan = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='xxxxxxxx')
```

Here is cancel the subscription in form.py:

```
class CustomUserForm(ModelForm):

   class Meta:
       model = CustomUser
       fields = ("username", "email", "stripe_id")

   def show_error(self, message):
       # pylint: disable=E1101
       self._errors[NON_FIELD_ERRORS] = self.error_class([message])
```

This is the error that I get:

```
'User' object has no attribute 'stripe_id'
```

I think that it could not save stripe_id to form and not retrieve from form.
How should I edit it ?

Comment: user do not have stripe is but customer have customer.stripe_id and show user and customer model completely

Comment: When I changed it to request.customer.stripe_id, it returns 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'customer'. How can I fetch customer by cancel_subscription function ?